# How to resolve 'vulnerabilities' in React Native project?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, command-line

I installed a npmjs plugin and it completely messed up my node modules and no matter how I tried to fix them my repo was just trashed.  So I re-cloned our app from a clean state and I am in a completely new folder now but I am still getting these 'vulnerabilities' errors.  I have deleted and re-cloned our app several times now to different places in shock that these errors keep following me even though these changes were never pushed or merged.  I tried running 'npm audit fix' and when that didn't work I tried 'npm auditx fix --force' but neither is fixing the problem.  I have deleted my package-lock.json file, node_modules folder, etc. and ran 'npm install' again but nothing is working!  Can someone please suggest a command that can fix or make these'vulnerabilities' go away?

```
C:\projects\mobile (master -> origin)
λ npm install

    > react-native-elements@0.19.1 postinstall C:\projects\mobile\node_modules\react-native-elements
    > opencollective postinstall


         *** Thank you for using react-native-elements! ***

    Please consider donating to our open collective
         to help us maintain this package.

      https://opencollective.com/react-native-elements/donate

                        ***


    > react-native-router-flux@4.0.0-beta.28 postinstall C:\projects\mobile\node_modules\react-native-router-flux
    > opencollective postinstall


         *** Thank you for using react-native-router-flux! ***

    Please consider donating to our open collective
         to help us maintain this package.

      https://opencollective.com/react-native-router-flux/donate

                        ***

    npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.1.3 (node_modules\fsevents):
    npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.1.3: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})

    added 1403 packages from 1139 contributors and audited 21924 packages in 91.44s
    found 811 vulnerabilities (693 low, 95 moderate, 23 high)
      run `npm audit fix` to fix them, or `npm audit` for details
```

Comment: I think you cannot do anything about this except fixing the vulnerabilities by yourself and sending a pull request or one way is you can downgrade the npm version below 6. This may be helpful https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/running-a-security-audit#fix-the-vulnerability

Comment: I tried updating the dependencies one by one but I just get more errors when I  do this.  I have re-cloned our app and start fresh everytime so I shouldn't be getting any of these errors at all.  My co-worker just cloned the app and built but he's not getting these errors.  Is there a way just to blow away these errors??

Comment: Check co-worker npm version with your npm. "npm -v"